# TeXstudio: excessive autocomplete

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

When I'm working in a math environment and I want to type something like `\sec^2x`, as soon as I type the `^` after the `\sec`, it autocompletes the `\sec` to `\section`.  Or when I'm working in a `tikzpicture` environment and I want to type `rotate = 90`, it will autocomplete `rotate =` to `rotate around x=` as soon as I type the `=`.  Is there a way to stop auto completion for specific commands?  I don't want to give up the automatically putting the `\end{}` for whatever environment I'm working in.

Edit: I'm working in TeXstudio version 4.7.2.  Some examples are I'm writing out some Pythagorean Identities:

```
\[\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta-1\]
```

Or I'm drawing a diagram and want some nodes rotated:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,0) -- (0,0);
    \node[anchor = south, rotate = 90] at (0,1.5) {Silo};
    \node[anchor = south, rotate = -90] at (0,1.5) {50 feet};
    \node[anchor = north] at (1.5,0) {Shadow};
    \node[anchor = south] at (1.5,0) {$L$};
    \node[anchor = south east, xshift = -.4cm] at (3,0) {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I hope this clarifies things.

Full Test Document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{College Precalculus Solutions}
\author{Sal Brusco}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{polynom} % polynomial long and synthetic division
\usepackage{xcolor} % highlight equations
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} %for the integer function \llbracket \rrbracket
\usepackage{dsfont} %for number sets \mathds{Z}
\usepackage{amssymb} %for square
\usepackage{parskip} % this adds space between paragraphs
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem} % numbering
\usepackage{amsmath} % aligning expressions and equations
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % gets me the heading at the top of each page
\usepackage{url} % gets the fancy url in the reference
\usepackage{graphicx} % i can put pictures in
\usepackage{pgfplots} %graphs
\usepackage{multicol} %put stuff in columns with \begin{multicol}{n}
\usepackage{multirow} %\multirow{number of rows}{width}{text}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}%so that pictures and text can appear side by side with
%\begin{wrapfig}{alignment}{image size}
%   \inputgraphics...
%\end{wrapfig}
%then text
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes} %triangles
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
% the following is the header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}

\newcounter{Ex}
\newenvironment{Ex}[ 1][]{
    \ifdim\pagetotal=0pt
    \else
    \rule{3in}{1px}
    \vspace{-1em}
    \fi
    \refstepcounter{Ex}
    \par\medskip
    \textbf{Ex~\theEx: #1}
    \rmfamily}{\medskip}
\numberwithin{Ex}{subsection} %puts the subsection number before example number
\newcommand{\degs}{^\circ}
\newcommand{\infinf}{-\infty,\infty}
\newcommand{\done}{\hspace{\fill}$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
    Pythagorean Identities:
    \[\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta\hspace{1in}\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta-1\hspace{1in}1=\csc^2\theta-\cot^2\theta\]
    \begin{Ex}
        Picture first.
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,0) -- (0,0);
                \node[anchor = south, rotate = 90] at (0,1.5) {Silo};
                \node[anchor = south, rotate = -90] at (0,1.5) {50 feet};
                \node[anchor = north] at (1.5,0) {Shadow};
                \node[anchor = south] at (1.5,0) {$L$};
                \node[anchor = south east, xshift = -.4cm] at (3,0) {$\theta$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        Now we have to make a function of $\theta$ that finds $L$.  Well we're dealing with the opposite and adjacent, so we use tangent.
        \begin{align*}
            \tan\theta &= \dfrac{50}{L}\\
            L &= \dfrac{50}{\tan\theta} = L(\theta)
        \end{align*}
    Part 1 done.  We have the function.  Now we just substitute the values into the function.  For $10\degs$, $L(10) \approx 283.56$ feet.  For $30\degs$, $L(30)\approx 86.60$ feet.  For $50\degs$, $L(50)\approx 41.96$ feet.
    \end{Ex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The behavior you're experiencing is related to the auto-completion feature of your LaTeX editor. First, you should probably share which LaTeX editor you use (e.g., TeXstudio, TeXmaker, Overleaf, etc.) since each editor has its own way of handling auto-completion.

Comment: Can you add a short test document so we can recreate the situation?

Comment: @chadoulis The editor is in the title

Comment: I can't reproduce this when typing a simple test document like this in texstudio: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \sec^2x
\]
\end{document}`

Comment: Can you add which version of texstudio you are using? And also show a screenshot of the "Completion" tab in your texstudio preferences?

Comment: Please add a complete test document. Your class and and packages might influence the autocompletion.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your preferences. Even with your document, I can't reproduce the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcjVB.gif

Comment: If you tell me how you made that gif, I can do that too.

Comment: That's puzzling! I've tried with exact same settings as in your screenshot and can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm downloading a screen recorder but it's taking forever... please hold.

Comment: (there are many tools to take screen recordings as gifs, personally I use https://github.com/onmyway133/GifCapture )

Comment: Got the gif for ya.

Comment: Thanks for the gif. That's really puzzling! At lest of the texstudio devs is a user here, I hope they will see your post. In case you don't get an answer here, you could try to ask at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues?q=is%3Aissue+

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I'll put the question there.

Comment: I guess that the option _Complete selected text when non-word character is pressed_ could be the problem, since you are pressing the `^` key.